# Jquery and Powerpoint

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, powerpoint, frontend

I have some MS Powerpoint slides that i want to display on my website. The problem
is that i don't want the users to download them or embed them or share them.

I have tried using some third party tools like GoogleDrive, PowerpointOnline, SlideShare etc...but all of them have similar issue.

My main concern is that **i don't want the users to give the option of download or embed or share**. I just want the slides to play on my website.

So my question is :

**Is there a way where i can turn off these features (Embed,Download,Share)
in GoogleDrive, PowerpointOnline, SlideShare etc.**

OR

**If there is no way to solve this issue then can i do something with javascript or jquery to play the Powerpoint slides on my website.**

OR

**If there is some plugin in wordpress to handle this.**

Answer (score 3):

> problem is that i don't want the users to download them or embed them or share them

You can't have something on a website and *not* allow the user to download it. The only way for a user to view ***anything*** on a website is for the user to download the resources to their machine. Typically this happens automatically where the browser downloads assets to a temporary location (or if the cache duration is high, a not-so-temporary location).

You may be able to host a different format of the file on your website, such as a series of images, instead of the raw powerpoint slides.

Be aware that anyone could then use those images to recreate the powerpoint deck.